# Serve static files from network share as gmsa

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I am trying to serve static files from a file server running Windows Server 2016.  I would like to use a group managed service account for the connection.

I have attempted configuring IIS on Windows Server 2012 to use the gmsa.  The Test-ADServiceAccount cmdlet returns True for the gmsa I am attempting to use on the IIS host.  I have gone under the basic settings option of the IIS site configuration and used the "connect as" button and set it to the gmsa account with no password.  The prompt then says "Connect as 'gmsa-foo$'".  However, when I attempt to press "ok", I get an error that the specified password is invalid.

Can I use a gmsa to allow access to the remotely hosted static files that I want to serve?  Do I need to use a particular version of Windows Server to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the gMSA account in the application pool identity.

[image]

It should be noted that this account may show unexpected behavior in IIS manager.  For example, if you click on “Basic Settings” for an application that uses this account for its application pool, “Test Settings” may give you an error indicating “the user name or password is incorrect”.  Usually, this can be ignored.  Browsing any page in the application would be a better test – as long as you don’t receive a 503 response, the application pool username/password is fine.

You could get more information from the below document:

[Windows Server 2012: Group Managed Service Accounts](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/ba-p/255910)

Comment: I've read that document but I was not able to proceed past the password error because the UI would not allow saving.  Can you confirm this works for you for serving static files from a network share restricted to the gmsa user?